# Jest giving error on directly using property name set on window object

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Suppose there is a property **person** set on the window object.
And obviously, we can directly use this property without writing **window** with the property.

I am testing a function that gets the name out of this **person** property but I am getting test case failed. Its says **ReferenceError: person is not defined**

If I am using window.person then it is working fine. But is there a way to configure jest to ignore these errors.

Comment: The problem you describe isn't common and shouldn't occur under normal circumstances. Please, provide a way to reproduce it, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Jest default environment is `dom` where `window === global` so it's impossible to cause this error if `window.person` exists, unless it's old Jest version or `node` environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `person` to the Jest `globals` object.

Ref:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globals-object